# copy artifacts from gitlab runners to windows shared drive

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Am new to gitlab runners. I need help with pipeline script to copy the artifact produced by gitlab pipeline( which runs on a linux runner and windows) to a windows share. Any help is appreciated.

The pipeline script is a gitlab-ci.yml file which in turn calls a .sh script.

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly what you mean? Do you want to copy files just for a particular pipeline/project or every artifact for all your projects? Are you using gitlab.com/shared runners or a self-hosted instance of GitLab?

Answer (score 1):

You can use samba and cifs-utils to mount the windows share on your runner and then use the gitlab-ci apis to download the artifact to those mounted paths.

check out - [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) and
[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434358/how-do-i-access-windows-shares-from-bash)